# Marking zonal statistics areas with a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, arcgis-10.5, zonal-statistics

I'm working with Lidar data, and my end goal is to get a collection of points representing cliff bands, with key information attributed to the individual points. So far I've been able to identify my cliffs create an area around the cliff and used this zone to find the range of elevation data around the cliff (approximate max height). I now have one raster that has a bunch of blobs with different pixel values.

[image: image of current situation]

I need help marking a point in the middle of each of these blobs that contains the raster value of their parent blob.

Comment: You have one raster for each of Min, Max etc.. combine with Combine http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Combine/009z0000007r000000/ then Raster to polygon http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000008000000 then Feature to Point http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003m000000

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you’re asking, I’d convert your blobs to polygons and then calculate the centroid using Feature to Point with the point location option set to “Inside.”